# Resizing HBox width to fit content

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, mxml

I have an HBox with a fixed Width and Height and a Border. In that HBox I have a viewStack with a few different views.
When the viewStack changes views, I want the HBox container to keep resizing to its content. Currently it stays at the fixed width.
Is there any way to do that with an HBox setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove all sizing on the HBox.  So remove any `width` or `percentWidth` attributes. Also make sure your `ViewStack` is resizing first.

Answer (score 0):

I've not done this myself, but here are a few links which might be helpful:

- [Make control resize itself to the children content](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/communityengine/index.cfm?event=showdetails&productId=2&postId=13087)
- [Resizing a Flex Accordion container to fit its contents](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/08/27/resizing-a-flex-accordion-container-to-fit-its-contents/)